# How to save checkbox status after form is submitted

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP code to display table data with a column of checkboxes used to click to mark the test case as Blocked. I am trying to save the state of checkbox after it is submitted, but I am unable to do so.
Please help!

```
echo "<form id=\"checkbox\" class=\"check2\" method = \"post\" action=\"\">";
$checked = "";
if(isset($_POST['Blocked[]'])) {
$checked = 'checked="checked"';
}
echo "<td $Blocked><input type =\"checkbox\" name=\"Blocked[]\" value=\"checkblock\"         onclick=\"showMsg('div1')\" $checked/></td>";             
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"button\" name=\"edit_tc\" onclick=\"myFunction(form)\" style=\"position:fixed; height:25px ; width:150px; bottom:25px; right:200px;\"/>";
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please don't echo the static html like above because it makes the code reading difficult. Secondly, you are using the isset() function incorrectly. Thirdly, your input field name for checkbox is of type array. Do you really need this to be an array?

Please use something like this:

```
<?php
$checked = '';
if(isset($_POST['Blocked'])) {
    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
}
?>
<form id="checkbox" class="check2" method = "post" action="">
<input type ="checkbox" name="Blocked" value="checkblock" onclick="showMsg('div1')" <?php echo $checked;?>/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" name="edit_tc" onclick="myFunction(form)" style="position:fixed; height:25px ; width:150px; bottom:25px; right:200px;"/>
</form>
```